# lynx proxy authorization

Tags: scripting, proxy, authentication, lynx

A number of scripts on my system are relying on `lynx` which in turn can't pass through my proxy. More specifically, `lynx` successfully picks up the global proxy settings except the user id and password fields, suggesting to use `-pauth` on the command line instead:

```
lynx -pauth=proxyuserid:proxypass
```

Which I can't easily do because lynx is called indirectly. But then how should I do it, to apply these settings globally, for all lynx invocations? A configuration file -- couldn't find anything about proxy authorization. A bash shell wrapper under the same name `lynx` invoking the actual `lynx` with `-pauth` - somehow I can't make it work.

**Update**. I have environment variables fully describing proxy, e.g.
`http_proxy=http://userid:pass@proxyserver:port`
from which Lynx correctly reads off the proxy server and port correctly, but not the user/pass fields for some reason (unlike wget for example).

Therefore, I'm now using a lynx wrap script as follows:

```
envproxy=${http_proxy%@*}
/usr/bin/lynx -pauth=${envproxy:7} "$@"
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question. How are the scripts called and how is `lynx` called from the scripts? How is `PATH` set for the scripts that call `lynx`. Maybe `wget` or `curl` could be used instead of `lynx`.

Comment: The CHANGES files indicates "accept userinfo in a URL, subject to override by -auth option or -pauth options.  According to RFC-3986, this is deprecated, but testing shows other clients support it -TD" -- have you tried the `http :// user:pw@url` syntax?

Comment: indeed, `parse_authentication()` appears to look for a colon to delimit a password.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `lynx` with a wrapper script will work if the scripts/programs call `lynx` without specifying the path, so the system will search it in the directories listed in variable `PATH`.

You have to find out where `lynx` is located, e.g. by typing `type lynx`.
I assume it might be `/usr/bin/lynx`.

The variable `PATH` for the scripts/programs that call `lynx` must have a different directory (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`) before the location of `lynx` (e.g. `/usr/bin`). If this is not the case you might have to extend `PATH`.

Example:

Assuming your `PATH` is set to

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin/X11
```

You could extend it with

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

in one of the startup scripts that set `PATH` for the scripts/programs. How exactly you can do this depends on how these scripts/programs get called.

Then you could create a shell script `/usr/local/bin/lynx` like this:

```
#! /bin/sh

# Here you could do what is needed to get the user name and password for the
# proxy authentication and use these instead of hard coded values.

/usr/bin/lynx -pauth=proxyuserid:proxypass "$@"
```

When a script/program wants to execute `lynx foo bar` it will find your script `/usr/local/bin/lynx` before it would find the "real lynx" in `/usr/bin/lynx`.

The script will then call `/usr/bin/lynx -pauth=proxyuserid:proxypass "foo" "bar"`.

Of course you can use a different location instead of `/usr/local/bin`.

This wrapper script solution will not work if the script/program executes lynx with specifying a path like `/usr/bin/lynx foo bar`. In such a case you could rename `/usr/bin/lynx` to e.g. `/usr/bin/lynx.real` and create a script `/usr/bin/lynx` that calls `/usr/bin/lynx.real` in the same way.

Comment: Thank you so much, your script works. Could you review one little modification that I've come up to? The script should ideally obtain the credentials from the environment variable (since lynx fails to do that by itself). This seems to work:

`envproxy=${http_proxy%@*}`

`/usr/bin/lynx -pauth=${envproxy:7} "$@"`

Comment: @rych Please add this to the question and show how variable `http_proxy` looks like. Instead of specifying an offset with `${envproxy:7}` it might be better to specify a pattern with `${envproxy#pattern}`

Comment: thank you @Bodo: I've updated the OP. I'm curious whether there is a one-liner extracting the credentials substring. And of course, why `lynx` can't read those fields off the environment variable by itself.